# Is there a way to make a loop until there isn't a runtime error

Tags: java, loops

I am using `JPanel`s to add a user interface to my program and I am converting the string that the user types into integers and sometimes, the user doesn't input numbers. Is there a way to make a loop where while there is a Runtime error, The loop continues going. Here is a small part of the code where I want to place the loop.

```
eventCreator = "Enter day of event";
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,new Object[] {eventCreator, userField2}, "Event Creator", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);
day=Integer.parseInt(new String(userField2.getText()));
```

Comment: `parseInt` will throw a `NumberFormatException` on bad input. You could put a `try/catch` inside a loop.

Comment: I guess a better solution would be to wrap the Integer.parsent in a try/catch and display a some warning so the user can retry.

Comment: Put a try/catch around the parseInt inside a while(true) loop. After the parseInt, put a break statement.

Comment: If your user-interface (UI) is completely graphical, then you probably have a `JTextField`, or similar, where the user enters the "number". There are many ways to check whether a `JTextField` contains a whole number. For starters, have a look at [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Integer day = null;
while (day == null) {
    try {
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,new Object[] {eventCreator, userField2}, "Event Creator", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options , options[0]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(new String(userField2.getText()));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe this answers the question and would work, so I wonder why it has been downvoted. Perhaps the downvoter could comment. I am always open to feedback.